# Syntax misunderstanding and confusion

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file and also try the Gauss elimination process. One thing that is unclear to me is the syntax of the ifstream, when you want to read a file. In on previous example the syntax was like this:

```
ifstream filein;
filein.open(Filename=name of the file I will read from)
if(not filein.good()){
cout <<"There's seems to be a problem";
exit(1);
```

Then in my current exercise the following is written:

```
ifstream dfile(fname=name of the file I will read from) ;
if( not dfile)
{
cout <<"There seems to be a problem";
exit(1);
}
```

In both cases we are trying to read what is in the file, now my questions are:

1 - Why aren't the code sequences the same since the same things is being done, meaning we are reading from a file?

2 - In the beginning we have file.open and in the other program we don't. Then we see **filein** in the first one and **dfile** in the next one. I tried google to find out what is the meaning of them but I got no results. Can someone explain to me how this reading/writing thing works? In our classes the professor didn't took the time to do so.

Comment: `if stream file in;` doesn't make sense to me. Are you asking why it is not `ifstream filein;`?

Comment: `filein` and `dfile` are variable names. You can choose them arbitrarily.

Comment: but if dfile and filein are variables names (which is suspected) then what about the name of the string/array which hold the name of the file that we summon? I don't understand the purpose of  dfile and filein

Comment: `Filename` and `fname` appear to _also_ be variable names and either will have the same functional effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code isn't the same because... there is almost always more than one way to write a program. The two examples are showing different approaches.

The first case uses the default constructor to create an `ifstream` object which, by default, doesn't open a file. Then, the `ifstream::open()` method is called to open a file. Finally, the method `ifstream::good()` is called to see if the file was opened successfully.

In the second case, a non-default constructor is used to initialize the `ifstream` object with the name of the file to read, and a different test is used. The `not` operator takes an operand of type `bool`, and so the compiler first calls the `operator bool` defined for `ifstream` to convert the object into a `bool`, which is used to determine whether a problem was encountered.

Note that, because there are various states that a file stream can in (for example, no file was found, or it couldn't be opened, or it was opened but we got to the end of it), these methods aren't necessarily going to give the same results.

There's more on this here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/?kw=ifstream

Comment: Tim, I have one additional question, do you have like 5 min in a chat room, that way I can try and explain my problem, cuz I don't want to make a thread in which I fail to properly explain what i don't understand

Comment: @imbAF I'm not familiar with chat rooms but you can always ask a question here. We can always delete comments after they've served their purpose... and if your questions are likely to be shared by other readers then I will update the answer to cover them.

Comment: Tim I have a program in which we read data from a file. This file contains a number, a matrix and an array. In the programm we define an integer type variable and then we equalize it with tthe ifstream variable which contains the data from the file. And when I do cout << the integer I get the on the screen the single digit number that is contained in the file, how does the program knows that? Why did it displayed the number and not on of the numbers of the matrix or the array?

Comment: @imbAF if I understand correctly, your code does something like this: `ifstream ifs(filename); float f; ifs>>f; cout<<f<<"\n";` and in that case, then the value of `f` is the result of attempting to read a floating point number from the file (from its beginning). Now, it sounds like the first number in the file is indeed the one that you wanted to read, so that looks okay. If you put the `ifs>>f; cout<<f<<"\n";` in a loop, you should expect to see the members of the matrix and array printed out, in the order that they appear in the file. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in you using `if stream file in` instead of `ifstream filein`.